# Mutating a Kubernetes deployment yaml for tolerations doc is missing

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, webhooks, kubectl, json-patch

I created a mutating admission webhook in my Kubernetes cluster.
The api mutation webhook adds tolerations to a Deployment YAML.
However, it says an error `Internal error occurred: jsonpatch add operation does not apply: doc is missing path: "/spec/template/spec/tolerations/"`

My Yaml Sample file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: webhook
  labels:
    app: nginx 
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 100%
      maxUnavailable: 50%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: "nginx:1.17"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: nginx
```

Python code:

```
     mutations = []
     mutations.append({"op": "add", "path": "/spec/template/spec/tolerations/" + str(counter),
 "value": {key: t[key]}})
```

However, upon testing error appears as stated above.
Please help. :(

Comment: can you check `"path": "/spec/template/tolerations/"` ?

Comment: hello @hoque thanks for the response. It is the same. I am still getting error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the whole file, therefore I cannot correct it.
But the problem is with your path, you are probably linking an array -- you have to specify an index. When you want to add an element to the end of an array, use `-1` like this: `spec/template/spec/containers/0/env/-1`

---

Have a look at this example

- shortened yaml file:

```
...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers: # this is an array, there is 0 in the path 
        - name: somename
          image: someimage
          env: # another array, we are putting the element at the end, therefore index is -1
          - name: SOME_VALUE_0
            value: "foo"
          - name: SOME_VALUE_1
            value: "bar"
          # I want to add second env variable SOME_VALUE_2 here
...
```

- `kustomization.yaml`

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
     - ../link/to/your/yaml
patchesJson6902:
     - target:
            ...
       patch: |-
            - op: "add"
              path: "/spec/jobTemplate/spec/template/spec/containers/0/env/-1"
              value: {name: "SOME_VALUE_2", value: "baz"}
```